# Custom HTML static cards using PHP Mirror API -Google Glass

Tags: php, html, google-glass, google-mirror-api, aero-glass

I wish to insert HTML formatted card in Google Glass timeline using Mirror API. I am using PHP PHP Mirror Client API. It takes message and image as argument, and displays that image in the background. Something like this:

```
 insert_timeline_item($mirror_service, $new_timeline_item, "image/jpeg", file_get_contents($image_url));
```

Any help about using custom card views with PHP Client library would be highly regarded. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom card views would be expressed by the HTML that you have set in the `$new_timeline_item` variable.

You can design the HTML using the Mirror API Playground at https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/playground

You would set this into the $new_timeline_item variable with something like

```
$html = '<article class="photo">'.
        '  <img src="attachment:0" width="100%" height="100%">'.
        '  <div class="overlay-gradient-tall-dark"/>'.
        '  <section>'.
        '    <p class="text-auto-size">Based on Hybrid Template</p>'.
        '  </section>'.
        '</article>';
$new_timeline_item->setHtml( $html );
```

The img URL of "attachment:0" means to use the first attachment as the image. The rest of the HTML was based on the HTML generated by the "Hybrid" template on the Playground - you can adjust as necessary.

Comment: This is great! I wonder how i missed that part! Thank you! Where can I find detailed documentation about PHP Client library? I wish to add a custom footer with time stamp and a logo as well. I am using <footer> tag in html like: <footer><img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...'/></footer> but it is not formatted correctly.

Comment: Both of these sound like separate questions that are best posted separately so they're not mixed up with the original question.